# How to call methods of .Net nested class from COM callers

Tags: c#, vbscript, com

I have a COM visible nested class that looks like below.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("12341234-3EDA-4A6D-9E84-804DCC625BE2")]
public interface ITestA
{
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestA))]
[Guid("922F3F5A-0B65-4B58-AB91-76822A4FAA00")]
public class TestA : ITestA
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("43211234-3EDA-4A6D-9E84-123DFC625BE2")]
    public interface ITestB
    {
        string SayHello();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestB))]
    [Guid("922F3F5A-0B65-4B58-AB91-76822A4FAA00")]
    public class TestB : ITestB
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

And I use VBScript to instantiate the TestB class like below.

```
Set objTestB = CreateObject("Application.TestA.TestB")
Wscript.Echo objTestB.SayHello()
```

This is giving an error "ActiveX component can't create object" while instantiation of the COM object.

Comment: This is giving an error "ActiveX component can't create object" while instantiation of the COM object.

Comment: You are trying to have two coclasses with the same CLSID. That ain't gonna fly. Once this is resolved, check whether and which ProgIDs for the two classes got registered. For a ProgID of, say, `Application.TestA.TestB`, there should be a registry key named `Application.TestA.TestB` under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. That key should have a subkey named `CLSID` whose default value is a GUID associated with the class. Finally, there should be a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` whose name is this GUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registering the COM library creates Application.TestA+TestB as CLSID. To instantiate with CreateObject("Application.TestA.TestB") add attribute ProgID in the c# code.

```
[ProgId("Application.TestA.TestB")
```